# How to pass object to d3-context-menu dynamic-menu-list

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For a project I use this context-menu: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-context-menu

The "dynamic-menu-list" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-context-menu#dynamic-menu-list) allows to write the menu as a function. This works fine. However, the function approch allows to pass data to the menu to differ what items to show.

I invoke the menu in a D3 tree layout like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr('class', function(d) {
        return 'nodeCircle ' + d.state;})
    .attr("r", 0)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        show_tooltip(d);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        hide_tooltip(d);
    })
    .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(node_menu)
    );
```

This works, but I want to pass "d" to "node_menu".

What I already tried:

`d3.contextMenu(node_menu(d))`

=> "d" is just the value "1"

```
.on("contextmenu", function(d) {
        d3.contextMenu(node_menu(d));
    })
```

=> Shows no context Menu at all, also not if I add return

How can I pass the "d" object to the "node_menu" function?

*Edit:*
Maybe helpful, the "node_menu" function:

```
var node_menu = function (data) {
    console.log('data:');
    console.log(data);

    if (data.depth == 6) {
        return  node_menu_v1;
    }
    else{
        return node_menu_v2;
    }
};
```

Comment: @gerardo-furtado I know which line of code you mean. However, if I just pass the "node_menu" function to d3.contextMenu() the value of "data" inside the "node_menu" function is just "1". I can access the "data" when an action is selected by the user because it gets passed by the line `d.action(elm, data, index);` but I can not present diffrent menus depending of "data" without the solution @riov8 provided. Or at least I don't know how.

Comment: The [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hAx36JQhb0RsvVn7TomS?p=info) is just about a static menu as array, not a dynamic menu as a function like here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-context-menu#dynamic-menu-list

Comment: Your edit and link made it more clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm sorry I caused some confusion, I'll try to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple menu structures, inside or outside the `data` array.

```
var data = [
  {v: 1, menu: menu1},
  {v: 2, menu: menu2},
  {v: 3, menu: menu3}
];
...
.on('contextmenu', function(d) { d3.contextMenu(d.menu)(d);} );
```

Comment: thanky you, exactly what I needed to know - the "(d)" does the trick. My working code is now:


.on("contextmenu", function(d) {
     d3.contextMenu(node_menu(d))(d);
});

Comment: @Seb depends on the menu variable, is it an array or function